# Availability Set in Availability Zone Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-availability-set, availability-zone

I’ve read somewhere that availability sets can be deployed in availability zones, however I can’t find the doc again. Now I cannot find the doc and can’t find anywhere to validate what was written. So my question is can an availability set be deployed in an availability zone, and if there’s any docs on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In an Availability zone you automatically get the functionality of an Availability Set.

> An Availability Zone in an Azure region is a combination of a fault
> domain and an update domain. For example, if you create three or more
> VMs across three zones in an Azure region, your VMs are effectively
> distributed across three fault domains and three update domains. The
> Azure platform recognizes this distribution across update domains to
> make sure that VMs in different zones are not scheduled to be updated
> at the same time.

See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview

Comment: Bhaji thanks for that, I have read that and it’s very informative, I’m just trying to understand how I would deploy an availability set in an availability zone, although you get the same functionality if I wanted to distribute my workload across a region could I not create a zone in an wv set in an av zone ..hope that makes sense

Comment: You cannot deploy an availability set in an availability zone. But you do not need to since an availability zone has all the functionality of an availability set. If the machines are in different data centers they are in different racks. MS does rolling updates so 2 zones will not be updated at the same time.

Comment: Thanks that’s great, just one last quick point, if I wanted the machines in a proximity placement group, would they all need to be in the same zone, without the need for an availability set?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-proximity-placement-groups/

Comment: A  proximity placement group cannot span zones. So you would use an availability set in conjunction with a proximity placement group